# Standard electrode potential

Tags: physical-chemistry, redox, reduction-potential

What is meant by the following:

> Electrode potential for $\ce{M^3+/M}$

Is it standard oxidation potential (SOP) or reduction potential (SRP)? What does a high positive or negative value for SRP and SOP tells us about the reactivity of the element?

Answer (score 1):

This is standard *reduction* potential or standard *electrode* potential $E^\circ$. More positive values refer to the strongly oxidizing agents, and more negative ones – to the strongly reducing agents. In order to convert SOP into SRP, reverse the sign. Examples and quotes from Atkins' *Elements of Physical Chemistry* [1, p. 209]:

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \ce{F2 + 2 e- &-> 2 F-} \quad &E^\circ = \pu{+2.87 V}\\
> \ce{Li + e- &-> Li+} \quad &E^\circ = \pu{-3.05 V}
> \end{align}$$
>
> The **standard potential**, $E$ (Ox/Red), of a couple Ox/Red is then measured by constructing a cell in which the couple of interest forms the right-hand electrode and the standard hydrogen electrode is on the left.
>
> [...]
>
> **A brief comment.** Standard potentials are also called *standard electrode potentials* and *standard reduction potentials*. If in an older source of data you come across a ‘standard oxidation potential’, reverse its sign and use it as a standard
>   reduction potential.

#### References

1. Atkins, P. W.; De Paula, J. *Elements of Physical Chemistry*, 5th ed.; Oxford University Press: Oxford ; New York, **2009**. ISBN 978-1-4292-1813-9.